# ZF2 add params to setPartial submenu

Tags: php, navigation, zend-framework2, partial

I use this partial to generate my submenu.

```
<?php foreach ($this->container as $page): ?>
    <?php foreach ($page->getPages() as $child): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $child->getHref(); ?>" class="list-group-item">
            <?php echo $this->translate($child->getLabel()); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which is called like this:

```
$this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setPartial('partial/submenu')->render();
```

But when i render the menu the "$child->getHref()" renders the url without the needed "slug/id" parameter.

I tried to create the url with "$this->url()" in ZF1 you could pass the params in an array to the partial but in ZF2 that doesn't seem to work anymore.

Can anybody tell me how to add the params to the menu urls?

Thanks in advance!

PS!

**I'm not referring to $this->Partial, i'm talking about $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setPartial('partial/submenu')->render() which apparently doesn't support a param array.**

Comment: my bad ... I understood you wrong

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, yes, you can pass params to partials. Example:

`<?php echo $this->partial('partial.phtml', array(
    'from' => 'Team Framework',
    'subject' => 'view partials')); ?>`

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html

I'm not sure this completely solves your issue, since you are not showing what the menu helper is. Is it your own view helper? Are you saying that setPartial method only accepts one argument?

All that said, have you considered Spiffy Navigation?
https://github.com/spiffyjr/spiffy-navigation

Comment: I'm not referring to $this->Partial, i'm talking about $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setPartial('partial/submenu')->render() which apparently doesn't support a param array.

Comment: You don't mention what `navigation` service factory you're using. I guess it's `Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory`? Can you share your navigation config? Is it set up similar to this? http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.navigation.quick-start.html

Comment: Yes, its the default navigation factory
    Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory

Answer (score 0):

It's been sometime since this question was asked, however today I came across the same problem (using version 2.4).

If you have a segment route to be included within the menu that requires some parameters there is no way to pass these through to the navigation's view partial helper.

The change I've made allows a `ViewModel` instance to be passed to the menu navigation helper's `setPartial()` method. This view model will be the context for the navigation's partial template rendering; therefore we can use it to set the variables we need for the route creation and fetch them just like within other views using `$this->variableName`.

The change requires you to extend the Menu helper (or which ever navigation helper requires it).

```
namespace Foo\Navigation;

use Zend\Navigation\AbstractContainer;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class Menu extends \Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
{
    public function renderPartial($container = null, $partial = null)
    {
        if (null == $container) {
            $container = $this->getContainer();
        }

        if ($container && $partial instanceof ViewModel) {
            $partial->setVariable('container', $container);
        }

        return parent::renderPartial($container, $partial);
    }

    public function setPartial($partial)
    {
        if ($partial instanceof ViewModel) {
            $this->partial = $partial;
        } else {
            parent::setPartial($partial);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Because this extends the default implementation of the helper updated configuration is required in `module.config.php` to ensure the extend class is loaded.

```
'navigation_helpers' => [
    'invokables' => [
         'Menu' => 'Foo\Navigation\Menu',
     ],
 ],
```

The menu helper will then accept a view model instance.

```
$viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
$viewModel->setTemplate('path/to/partial/template')
          ->setVariable('id', $foo->getId());

echo $this->navigation()
          ->menu()
          ->setPartial($viewModel)
          ->render();
```

The only change in the actual partial script will require you to create the URL's using the URL view helper.

```
foreach ($container as $page) {
    //...
    $href = $this->url($page->getRoute(), ['id' => $this->id]);
    //...
}
```